# Angular state change through d3.chart directive on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Back for another Angular question. I am working on a directive that uses d3.charts provided by the miso project, and have been running into issues. I am trying to set up an on click event during the insert portion of the lifecycle. This on click event will change the state to a new view and controller. So far the click takes me to an empty page with the same url parameters, but when I click elsewhere on the page it updates the url and changes the view. Let me set up an example.

```
var d3 = require('d3');
require('...thechart');
/*@ngInject*/
var genericDirective = function($state){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
      //directive arguments 
    }
  },
  template://some template

 link: function(scope, element){

 //chart design logic
 //......
 var chart = d3.select(element[0])
   .append('svg')
   //other chart things ...
   .on('click', function(data){
     $state.go( 'myState', {someArgs: data});
   })
   .chart(//bring in theChart//)
     //chart attributes....
    ;

 chart.draw(scope.data);
 }


}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the new url is correct based on the data passed to `$state.go()` even though page is blank?

Comment: yes. It correctly navigates to the page, but only after clicking off of the blank view loaded up.

Comment: `off of the blank view`? Try to be as descriptive as you can. No idea what that means

Comment: So, it is loading a partial view. the page is a sidebar, main view, and top panel. The ui router loads up the main view and a sidebar. These are both blank. The url is the same from the previous page, then clicking the top panel refreshes the url and the main view. Hope that is more clear.

Comment: Ok...but what should it do ? We have no controller to look at to even help debug. Also what errors are thrown? Directive looks fishy because you don't inject `$scope` in a directive

Comment: I'm sorry. that was done on the fly to look like my actual work. It's injecting $state. There are no errors with the controller. It is looking for the stateParams and writing them out. It does this after the correct url is loaded. It should just load up the view and write out the passed in params. It seems like a digest or apply needs to be called or an issue with how the url is being handled

Comment: did u wire you $stateProvider correctly?  You need to include a url template like localhost:8100/app/:id to extract the value in $stateParams.

Comment: @AndroidNoob I did, I can go to other states without a problem. I am even navigating to this from other areas of my application just fine. It seems to be breaking on the integration into a directive and the d3.charts library.